Convergence in distribution of random variables with symmetric distribution
I found the following question in the probability course materials: let $ (X_n)_{n\geq 1} $ be i.i.d. random variables with symmetric distributions such that $\sigma^2=\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]<\infty$. Let $S_n=\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{X_k}{\sqrt{k}}$. Then we have the following convergence in distribution: $$\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{\ln{n}}} \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2).$$
My idea was to apply central limit theorem, but I'm not sure what to do with that $\ln$ in the first place. So another approach was to prove the convergence of characteristic function, but apart from the fact that they are real due to symmetric distributions, I don't see much there either. Can you help me?

Seeing as $Var(S_n) \sim \ln(n)$, I have a hunch the standard procedure will work: Apply Lindeberg-Feller to the triangular array $Y_{nj} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{Var(S_n)}}\frac{X_j}{\sqrt{j}}$ to obtain $Y_{n1} + \dots + Y_{nn} \to N(0, 1)$.
